# Texture are not showing when I export (in FBX)

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, export

I downloaded this file and tried to export as an FBX to add texture [image]. But when I finish to export it the texture is not applied to it [image][image].

I am confused on how to export this one I watched sort of videos on youtube but doesn't work on mine, it's been week since I started learning on this.

Also I attached the file link with the edited (shown below) and original file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DYWafm-P4kzho4Ym0A_0plXiD0tIqRGA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: It's probably because the fbx doesn't understand correctly your node organization (Add Shader, Color Attribute...), instead use a Principled BSDF with Image Texture nodes plugged into it?

Comment: Seems that the I could only use the texture directly to principled bsdf :(